# How to correctly save iOS application state?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am developing a music player application which is able to play music in the background. As long as the music is playing the application won't get terminated anyway, but if the playback is stopped and the application is in background it may get terminated. To get the application more user-friendly I want to save the playback queue and state when the app is being terminated by the system so I implemented the following lines in the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    /*
     Archive the current queue controller to be able to continue the playback like the app never has been terminated
     when user is launching it again.
     */
    SMKQueueController *queueController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] queueController];
    [coder encodeObject:queueController forKey:@"queueController"];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    /*
     Restore the recently used queue controller to be able to continue the playback like the app never has been
     terminated when use is launching it again.
     */
    SMKQueueController *queueController = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"queueController"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setQueueController:queueController];
    return YES;
}
```

Sometimes (especially when I kill it manually via the double-tap-home-button menu) it works as I would expect it to work. But sometimes this methods aren't called when the application is being terminated.

So my question is: **Did I misunderstood how the methods work or what they are for? Or is there any better place to implement such a functionality?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attended a WWDC 2012 session describing exactly how this should be done. If you are a registered Apple developer, then you can access the videos from the sessions. This one is titled, "Saving and Restoring Application State on iOS". I found this to be a very informative session on this topic.